# Is there an add-on that lets you build using meshes in Blender?

Tags: add-on

I was wondering... if I were to create a set of blocks or pieces that fit together in Blender, would there be an add-on that would let me select one of those blocks and simply place them like in a level editor for a game? This would be much easier than copying, pasting, and dragging each individual block into place. Ty!

Comment: You mean like a tile-map?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Kind of, but if a tile-map were 3D

Comment: I think the closest blender can do is by using the array modifer. You can use curves to set custom paths if necessary, and you can stack arrays. However, I'm not sure how you'd manage random offsets if you needed something like that.

Comment: There is also the addon SPRyTile but I think it ony builds 3D scenes out of 2D tiles.